# can you use ref to reference different elements ? depending on some action in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to target the clicked btn using ref the problem is I always get the second one any idea to solve this issue ?
and lets say i have a 1 native select element that has 2 optgroups and I want know from which optgroup the selection is coming ? can I use ref to my advantage in this case ?

```js
let refData = useRef('');

    const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(refData.current);
    // Console log shows only the second btn even if i click on the first
    }

    <button ref={refData} label={'btn1'} onClick={handleClick}>
    1
    </button>

    <button ref={refData} label={'btn2'} onClick={handleClick}>
    2
    </button>
```

```js
<NativeSelect  name='excercises' onChange={handleSelect}>
          <optgroup label={'opt1'} >
            {optionsA.map((option, index) => (
              <option key={option.id}>{option}</option>
            ))}
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label={'opt2'} >
            {optionsB.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.id}>{option.supplment}</option>
            ))}
          </optgroup>
        </NativeSelect>
```

Comment: you can only use 1 ref per element.

Comment: so I cannot chant the value ? back and forth ?

Comment: correct........

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen - That's incorrect. You can change the ref from one button to another. You can't use the same ref on two elements *at the same time*, but you can absolutely use it for different elements at different times. (But I don't see any reason to above.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well, yes, with condition rendering, you can use either one, but in this case, they want both on screen...which i why I said he can only use the ref once, unless they plan to change their code.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen - Both can be *on the page* at once, but only one of them can have the ref, yes. They said "back and forth" suggesting one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

> can you use ref to reference different elements ? depending on some action in react?

Yes, but you probably don't need or want a ref for what you seem to be doing. It certainly won't tell you which button was clicked inside `handleClick`.

If you need to reference the button that was clicked in `handleClick`, you can do that via the event object:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    const btn = e.target.closest("button");
    // ...use `btn` here...
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const Example = () => {
    
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        const btn = e.target.closest("button");
        // ...use `btn` here...
        console.log(`Clicked button text: ${btn && btn.textContent}`);
    };
    
    return <div>
        <button label={'btn1'} onClick={handleClick}>
        1
        </button>
        <button label={'btn2'} onClick={handleClick}>
        2
        </button>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

**But**, regarding the question in your title: You can only use a ref for one element *at a time*. So to use it for different elements based on a condition, keep track of which one you want the ref to refer to, and then either do or don't use it on that element when rendering.

For instance, let's say you have a state member (I'll call it `whichButton`) that contains `"btn1"` if you want the ref on `btn1` and `"btn2"` if you want it on `btn2`:

```
<button ref={whichButton === "btn1" ? refData : undefined} label={'btn1'} onClick={handleClick}>
1
</button>

<button ref={whichButton === "btn2" ? refData : undefined} label={'btn2'} onClick={handleClick}>
2
</button>
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useRef, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [whichButton, setWhichButton] = useState("btn1");
    const refData = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Ref button text: ${refData.current && refData.current.textContent}`);
    }, [whichButton]);
    
    return <div>
        <button ref={whichButton === "btn1" ? refData : undefined} label={'btn1'}>
        1
        </button>
        <button ref={whichButton === "btn2" ? refData : undefined} label={'btn2'}>
        2
        </button>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    checked={whichButton === "btn1"}
                    onChange={() => setWhichButton("btn1")}
                />
                Use btn1
            </label>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    checked={whichButton === "btn2"}
                    onChange={() => setWhichButton("btn2")}
                />
                Use btn2
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let refData1 = useRef('');
let refData2 = useRef('');

const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(refData.current);
}

<button ref={refData1} label={'btn1'} onClick={handleClick}>1</button>
<button ref={refData2} label={'btn2'} onClick={handleClick}>2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `ref`. Try this:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
};
```

And define your buttons like this:

```
<button name='btn1' onClick={handleClick}>1</button>

<button name='btn2' onClick={handleClick}>2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an array:

```js
let refData = useRef([]);
```

An set an ref by this way:

```js
ref={el => itemsRef.current[0] = el}
```

For second element:

```js
ref={el => itemsRef.current[1] = el}
```

Then, you can access all of these elements, by single refData.

However, this will be better way for you:

```js
const handleClick = e => {
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

Using **e.target** property, you don't have to define refs.